# Xamarin Storyboard not rendering properly after build 661

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xcode-storyboard

After updating for the last Xamarin version, our storyboard stopped rendering properly.

[image: Xamarin Storyboard on our project]

We already tried going back on previous commits that we were sure that were working. Opening on Xcode works ok, but does not fix Xamarin view and seems to change the entire file with fixes.

Has anyone passed through this and fixed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Xcode storyboard, it is way better. Xamarin storyboard causes lot of issues especially if it gets big enough and also you never know when will it stop working after you update Xamarin studio.

Comment: At the we discovered that the file was corrupted. We still don't know why, but as the Xamarin Storyboard is not consistent we started using the Xcode one too! ;)

Comment: Anyway thanks for the advice! It helps certifying us that this is the best path.